# How to immediately enable the wait cursor until an operation is finished?

Tags: mouse-pointer

When performing an operation which often takes a few seconds, how can the hourglass mouse pointer be shown immediately using Lisp?

Otherwise, the default behavior is to show the hourglass after some delay (a second by default).

Comment: What is "a waiting mouse-cursor"?  And, is a "waiting mouse-cursor" something that Emacs controls, or is this OS dependent; and, if OS dependent, what OS does this question pertain to?

Comment: When performing some operations emacs sets the busy cursor. Just checked the C source code, this looks to be implemented via `start_hourglass`, `cancel_hourglass`.

Comment: Thanks.  Then, how about customizing the value of the variable `hourglass-delay`, which has a default value of 1 second; e.g., change it to something like 0 instead?:  "*Documentation:  Seconds to wait before displaying an hourglass pointer when Emacs is busy.*"

Comment: Setting to zero disables the hourglass entirely, setting to a small float value makes it show quicker, but not immediately.